# Melt a matrix using extern covariate in R

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2, melt

I have a matrix:

```
mat1 <- matrix(rnorm(8), ncol = 4;
  ,dimnames=list(c('R1','R2'),c('C1','C2','C3','C4')))

> mat1
          C1         C2         C3        C4
R1  1.226139 -1.0604743 -0.1803689 0.3852505
R2 -1.232622 -0.5567295 -0.4146919 0.2433812
```

and a covariate that match names of the matrix columns

```
> covariate   <- factor(c('A','A','B','B'))
> t(data.frame(covariate, colnames(mat1)))
               [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
covariate      "A"  "A"  "B"  "B" 
colnames.mat1. "C1" "C2" "C3" "C4"
```

I would like to melt it with respect to the covariate in order to have the following result:

Melting the data gives:

```
> melt( mat1 )
      Var1 Var2      value
    1   R1   C1  1.2261395
    2   R2   C1 -1.2326215
    3   R1   C2 -1.0604743
    4   R2   C2 -0.5567295
    5   R1   C3 -0.1803689
    6   R2   C3 -0.4146919
    7   R1   C4  0.3852505
    8   R2   C4  0.2433812
```

However I would like to get the following result:

```
covariate_2 <- factor( c(rep('A',4) , rep('B',4) ))
> data.frame( covariate_2 , melted_data )
  covariate_2 Var1 Var2      value
1           A   R1   C1  1.2261395
2           A   R2   C1 -1.2326215
3           A   R1   C2 -1.0604743
4           A   R2   C2 -0.5567295
5           B   R1   C3 -0.1803689
6           B   R2   C3 -0.4146919
7           B   R1   C4  0.3852505
8           B   R2   C4  0.2433812
```

I think there must be a way to get the results using standard melt function. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Use `set.seed` if sharing sample data created with functions that generate random numbers.

Comment: You can add the `covariate_2` - column after melting the data with a `ifelse` as it only depends on the values of `Var2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it's easiest to just rename the columns of your matrix first, and then `melt`.

Here are a couple of examples, first using "data.table", and second using the "tidyverse":

```
library(data.table)
setDT(melt(`colnames<-`(mat1, paste(c('A','A','B','B'), colnames(mat1), sep = "_"))))[
  , c("cov", "V1") := tstrsplit(Var2, "_")][, Var2 := NULL][]
#    Var1      value cov V1
# 1:   R1  1.2261390   A C1
# 2:   R2 -1.2326220   A C1
# 3:   R1 -1.0604743   A C2
# 4:   R2 -0.5567295   A C2
# 5:   R1 -0.1803689   B C3
# 6:   R2 -0.4146919   B C3
# 7:   R1  0.3852505   B C4
# 8:   R2  0.2433812   B C4


library(tidyverse)
`colnames<-`(mat1, paste(c('A','A','B','B'), colnames(mat1), sep = "_")) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  gather(var, val, -rowname) %>%
  separate(var, into = c("cov", "var1"))
#   rowname cov var1        val
# 1      R1   A   C1  1.2261390
# 2      R2   A   C1 -1.2326220
# 3      R1   A   C2 -1.0604743
# 4      R2   A   C2 -0.5567295
# 5      R1   B   C3 -0.1803689
# 6      R2   B   C3 -0.4146919
# 7      R1   B   C4  0.3852505
# 8      R2   B   C4  0.2433812
```

Sample data:

```
mat1 <- structure(c(1.226139, -1.232622, -1.0604743, -0.5567295, -0.1803689, 
    -0.4146919, 0.3852505, 0.2433812), .Dim = c(2L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
        c("R1", "R2"), c("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4")))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hi, sure it work and as you showed there are many way to get the result. However I was interested in a builtin function. Maybe such function does not exist. Also I am intrigued by the <pre>`colnames<-`<code> syntaxe. I have tested it with '`+`(1,1)' and it worked !. First time I see it. How do I accept your answer ?

Comment: @marc, see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @marc, the closest you're going to get in base R would be `stack`. I'm commenting from my phone right now, but will try to post an example in a few hours when I'm back in front of a computer.